# Eclipse plug-in to show docstring in a widget/window in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse

I am looking for an Eclipse plug-in compatible with PyDev that can show the docstring in a widget/window that will keep shown until next docstring is triggered. By default in PyDev the docstring is shown in hover and is disappeared after typing anything.

[image]

E.g., in R studio, one can use <kbd>F1</kbd>:

[image]

Matlab has an equivalent feature, also triggered with <kbd>F1</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Sounds useful so may be worth adding a feature request on https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Sounds good, I created a feature request, thanks! https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/757